# 2D canvas library for OpenLayers. Drawing custom interactive objects

Tags: javascript, openlayers, mapcanvas, draw-interaction, drawing

I am looking for the 2D canvas library like [Konva.js](https://konvajs.org) that I can use above OpenLayers 5.x.
I need to draw shapes with font inside that are interactive - can be dragged over the map to the appropriate location and rotated.
On the image below there is how it looks like with Konva.js over the image background.
Can you advise proper libs or techniques so the same can be implemented over the OpenLayers map?

[image: what I have now with Konva.js]

Comment: did you find any? im having the same problem